# Парсинг Binance Python

Tags: python, парсер

Добрый день мне нужно получить текущую цену криптовалюты в паре LTC/USDT.
Подскажите как это можно сделать через  api binance или же спарсить сайт.
Ссылка --> `https://www.binance.com/ru/trade/LTC_USDT?theme=dark&type=spot`

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/binance.html